# Keeping track of arguments sent as pointers in nested functions

Tags: c++, pointers

I have two functions accepting pointers as arguments, and one of them contains inside itself a call to another using its input argument, e.g.

```
foo(int* x)
{ 
   //... 
}

goo(int* y)
{
   //...
   foo(y) ; // I don't like this line, would prefer something like foo(&y)
}
```

Now, the reason I want to use pointers in the first place is so that when I call the function it is easy to see its argument might be modified by it, i.e.

```
foo(&xyz)
```

as opposed to

```
foo(xyz) // this looks like foo() accepts a copy, not actual variable
```

But now when I call `foo()` from `goo()`, I lose this visual cue of & in front of argument, since y in `goo()` is of type `int*`, or what `foo()` expects, and so I cannnot write `foo(&y)`. And I'm wondering whether there is any way around it that would make it clear from call to `foo()` inside `goo()` that `foo()` doesn't accept a copy, but the actual variable, and that it is able to permanently alter arguent sent to it.
Hmmm, I hope I don't sound too confusing :|

Comment: If you have a problem here, the problem is with the function names, not the parameter passing. Why doesn't foo() sound like something that changes its parameter, like `increment(x)`?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that your desire to avoid references made you miss one thing: the `x` and `y` arguments of your functions are now pointers. That means foo(y) doesn't modify `y` at all (and indeed it can't, since it's argument is a copy of `y`). It modifies the value *pointed by* `y`.

I guess you are trying to find an equivalent to C#'s explicit `ref` modifier, but there just isn't one in C++. I know some people try to emulate this behavior with pointers, but as you've seen yourself, that won't do, since the semantics of pointers is different. In fact, pointers will actually make things even more unsafe, since you can accidentally modify their address (instead of their referenced value) directly, and that's why I think you shouldn't use them unless you really need, well, pointers.

Yeah, C++ implicit passing of references may seem unsettling to some, but that's the way it works, and it goes all through C++'s design: there's a clear aversion from being explicit and verbose. Mind you, this is not just references that are subject to this: far more important that that is the constness of arguments. You don't explicitly specify anywhere whether an argument must be const or non-const. You're not even always sure if you invoke the const or non-const version of a member function. And that's OK, because you should be able to inspect the function declaration using intellisense or by jumping to its declaration with a hotkey.

Answer (score 0):

You could say:

```
foo( & (*y) );
```

But please don't. Just learn to read the code better.

Comment: Not that I want to encourage this pattern, but would most compilers optimize this away?

Comment: @Ryan Who knows? If you are interested, experiment.

Comment: @Ryan Thompson: depends:  the `*` operator can be overloaded. Iterators are a good example. But my guess is also that in this case, any decent compiler would indeed optimize it.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use *references* ?

```
foo(int& x)
{ 
   //... 
}

goo(int& y)
{
   //...
   foo(y);
}
```

It doesn't make the intent any less clearer.

Comment: Because here again I don't have any cue that calls to foo() or goo() can permanently alter their arguments.

Comment: @Puchatek: Actually, you do, because a well designed implementation who does **not** modify its parameters would mark them as `const`.

Comment: But you don't see it from a call, only from definition, and I would really like to be able to see that when calling the function without looking up its definition.

Comment: @Puchatek: no offense, but if one follows this rationale, what use do references have ? To me, a well written documentation with a simple function prototype is far more readable than a complex function call cluttered with `*` and `&`.

Comment: @Puchatek: That's what Intellisense and other forms of code-hinting are for. That's why you don't - and shouldn't - write C++ with Notepad.

Comment: @Boaz I can and should write C++ with vi, without code hinting.

Comment: @ereOn - I'm not criticizing references or anything, but they aren't the solution to what I'm asking for.

Comment: @Puchatek: I think you are focusing on the wrong concerns. Very well written libraries (like Boost) use references **a lot**. If your overall design and function naming is well tought, this shouldn't be a problem at all.

Comment: @unapersson: well, I'd write it with vim if I had to, but only with code hinting or with a macro for jumping to definition. Otherwise you couldn't really know what the function you're calling is doing, whether its arguments are const or non-const, copies, references or rvalues, etc. Using vi without any specific extensions for that is plain asceticism. Sure, I could (and did) write assembly with COPY CON FILE.ASM in the old DOS days. Great geek prowess to me, but it was kinda waste of time, and not really fun.

Comment: @Boaz - I appreciate Intelisense's capabilities. Reason I stick with Notepad++ is that all IDEs I saw so far would occlude a quarter of the screen with various panes that I hardly ever need, and would force me to create an entire project with a bunch of files of which purpose I simply don't understand, even though all I need to manage my files is a single m-file. Ou, and IDEs I tried don't come with clone view, a huge drawback.

Comment: Actually, getting to know an IDE you can fix most of those things. In Visual Studio, for instance, I usually close most of these panes (instead of the leftmost one, since I don't like my screen being *too* wide :)). Clone view is also possible, AFAIK. And while you can't avoid project files (if you want Intellisense), I find it a fair compromise. But if you don't like them, you can always put them in a faraway directory. The plus side for me, is being able to compile and debug inside the IDE, and all the useful keyboard shortcuts.

Answer (score 0):

It is slightly tangential to your question, however you may want to look into const correctness ([here](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Const-correctness) or [here](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-correctness.html)).

> In computer science, const-correctness is the form of program correctness that deals with the proper declaration of objects as mutable or immutable.

Whilst it will not be immediately obvious, you should be able to tell whether an argument will be modified simply by looking at a function definition rather than inspecting the function in depth. Additionally, I'm assuming that developers will respect the convention as well and not cast away the const, etc (see the second link above).

Comment: Yes, I can of course clear out any doubts just by looking at function declaration, I was just wondering if a neat method exists to get this information from function calls.

Comment: @Puchatek, Well, const correctness combined with code-hinting (intellisense et al.) should be able to give you this information, however I personally like using vim and tmux (although I'm not insistant on it) so I wont begrudge you if this is impractical :)

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible. The only way I see is to put a comment (plain and simple):

```
goo(int* y)
{
   //...
   foo(y) ; // foo receives pointer y and its content can be modified
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foo(xyz) // this looks like foo() accepts a copy, not actual variable
```

Use references more. Use const more. Then without context that snippet will look like `foo` *potentially modifies* `xyz`. Or with context you will see that it copies/mutably references/const references `xyz` (delete as appropriate).

Pointers are for things that potentially don't exist (elsewhere)

Your usage now has *more* things to track the changes of. First the *pointed-to* value, and also the *pointer* value, and thus potentially unbounded other *pointed-to* values.